# What is the meaning of "potentially allowing for one thread-bound Connection per DataSource" in DataSourceTransactionManager API?

Tags: spring, scope, transactions, connection, datasource

I was reading the API description of Spring's DataSourceTransactionManager class. However, there are couple of things that I don't understand from the description.

Here is the part of description that I don't understand.

> Binds a JDBC Connection from the specified DataSource to the current thread, potentially allowing for one thread-bound Connection per DataSource.

> Note: The DataSource that this transaction manager operates on needs to return independent Connections. The Connections may come from a pool (the typical case), but the DataSource must not return thread-scoped / request-scoped Connections or the like. This transaction manager will associate Connections with thread-bound transactions itself, according to the specified propagation behavior. It assumes that a separate, independent Connection can be obtained even during an ongoing transaction.

Two things that makes me confused is that,

1. when it says "potentially allowing for one thread-bound Connection per DataSource." Is that mean it only allows one thread-bound Connection per DataSource at a time even though there are many unused free connections left in the connection pool? So that it only supports one user at a time? Isn't it supposed something like "potentially allowing for one thread-bound Connection per Transaction?"
2. It says "the DataSource must not return thread-scoped / request-scoped Connections or the like," because the transaction manager itself bound the connection to the currently executing thread. Therefore, it says that the DataSource should return independent Connections. what are exactly the independent Connections mean here though? a plain Connection instance that does not have any scope?

Thank you and I appreciate your help,

Comment: Now I read the description again and it seems as the "per DataSource" part means that the DataSourceTransactionManager supports thread-bound transaction service per DataSource class the developer uses in their application. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

In plain English, it says that:

1. It is the transaction manager's job to ensure **only one connection is used by (dedicated to servicing) a given thread at any given time** (and so, it **does** support multiple users, because your application can simultaneously execute different transactions in separate threads)
2. **Precisely because** scoping connections to a thread is the transaction manager's job, the data source itself should not attempt to do the same (because that would be in conflict with what the transaction manager is already doing)

I am assuming *potentially* simply means there might not be enough connections in the pool for each thread in your application to hold on to one, and not all threads even need *a* connection.